# How to add legend labels per plotted column to multiple scatterplot subplots?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a created multiple scatterplot subplots with this code:

```
# Value counts of the samples in each cluster
counts = clustered_series.value_counts()
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 4, figsize = (35.7, 16))
for clust, ax in zip(np.unique(clusters), axs.flat):
    tickers = list(clustered_series[clustered_series==clust].index)
    means = sample.loc[tickers][tickers].mean()
    data = sample.loc[tickers][tickers].sub(means)
    pairs = list(itertools.combinations(data.columns, 2))
    for pair in pairs:
        sns.scatterplot(data = data, x = pair[0], y = pair[1], ax = ax)
    ax.set_title(label='Stock Alphas Correlation for Cluster %d' % clust)
plt.suptitle("Stocks' Alphas Clusters by Correlation", fontsize = 14, weight = 'bold')
fig.tight_layout()
```

This what `counts` looks like:

```
2    13
7    11
3    10
5     8
1     7
6     6
4     5
dtype: int64
```

And this is my scatterplot:

[image]

What i'm doing is to plot every possible pair of columns and rows per cluster one vs another within each subplot. I have a subtable per cluster. This is the table of cluster 7:

[image]

I want to distinguish each point by color attending to which stock (column or row) that points belongs to and show this in each subplot's legend. For example, if i had 8 pairs of stocks in cluster 1, i would like to display in the legend the unique stock names and the points in the plot should have a color per unique stock within the 8 pairs. I have tried the `hue` parameter of `sns.scatterplot` but it creates a huge legend per plot where a color is assigned to each point, and that's not what i want.

How can i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got it solved by changing the call from `plt.scatter` to `ax.scatter` and passing a list of the unique feature names in each pair to the `ax.legend` call like this:

```
# Value counts of the samples in each cluster
counts = clustered_series.value_counts()
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 4, figsize = (35.7, 16))
for clust, ax in zip(np.unique(clusters), axs.flat):
    tickers = list(clustered_series[clustered_series==clust].index)
    means = sample.loc[tickers][tickers].mean()
    data = sample.loc[tickers][tickers].sub(means)
    #data['clusters'] = clusters[clusters == clust]
    pairs = list(combinations(data.columns, 2))
    for pair in pairs:
        ax.scatter(x = data[pair[0]], y = data[pair[1]], cmap = 'Dark2')
    ax.set_title(label='Stock Alphas Correlation for Cluster %d' % clust)
    ax.legend(np.unique(np.concatenate(pairs)).tolist())
plt.suptitle("Stocks' Alphas Clusters by Correlation", fontsize = 14, weight = 'bold')
fig.tight_layout()
```

This is the result i'm getting now, which is exactly what i wanted:

[image]

Hopefully, this will hepl someone.